# what does the "a cap of" mean in following paragraph?

Tags: meaning

I recently received a letter from a journal, the following words are confusing with me, I　do not know exact meaning of `a cap of`.

> Please also be aware of TCYB page length policy with **a cap of** 12 pages plus two additional pages with a charge of $175/page, for a regular paper, provided that you promise to pay the bill after the publication.

Comment: "cap" is used here [in the sense of "*limit*"](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/cap): *an upper limit (as on expenditures): ceiling*

Comment: _Maximum_ is another synonym.

Comment: This just makes me realize why papers I've read on IEEE are never longer than 14 pages.

Comment: @DamkerngT. Yes, it's coming from ieee

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*To cap* means *to prevent from going higher than* or *to be unable to go higher than*.

Thus, *cap* as a noun can mean an upper limit.  It's often used to mean a "hard" or absolute upper limit.  Usually anything "below" a "cap" will "pass through" OK.

When used in this context, to me it is implying they will process only the first 12 pages you submit, should you submit more than 12, without willing or being able to warn you.